# Searching usernames containing special characters

Tags: mysql

To start off with, I have looked into this issue and gone through quite a few suggestions here on SO, but many leave me in doubt whether they are good performance-wise.

So to my problem:

I have a table with usernames and want to provide users the possibility to search for others by their name. As these names are taken from Steam though, the names not containing some form of special character are in the minority.

The easiest solution would be to use `LIKE name%`, but with the table size constantly increasing, I don't see this as the best solution, even though it may be the only one.

I tried using a fulltext search, but the many special characters crushed that idea.

Any other solutions or am I stuck with `LIKE`?

Current table rows: 120k+

Comment: you could use regexp (`where username regexp <expression>`) for more complex search queries, though `LIKE` will most likely be more performant if its capabilities are enough for you. Also, 120k rows aren't much, mysql can handle this with ease.

Comment: I'm assuming using an index and only using a wildcard at the end of the search string could negate some of the "performance loss"?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't believe that string-functions are faster, but contemporary I don't got any big database for testing performance. Let's give it a try:

```
WHERE substr(name, 1, CHAR_LENGTH('ste')) = 'ste'
```

Comment: Interesting idea, definitely going to try that out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest one solution which I applied before.

1. First of all, I clean all special characters from the string in name column.
2. Then I store cleaned string in another column (called cleaned_name) and index (fulltext search) this column instead of the original column.
3. Finally, I used the same function in step 1 to clean the queried name before executing a fulltext search on cleaned_name.

I hope that this solution is suitable for you.